# How to set up facebook pixel "submit button" tracking

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, tracking

I have a working facebook pixel that is tracking the audience on my website.

```
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');


fbq('init', 'myID');
fbq('track', "PageView");</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=myID&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
```

Ok, so this is working fine. Now my question is, how to set up this code, so i'll track

1. website audience (this is already working)
2. clicks on submit button

I would also need help with creating custom pixel in facebook panel (https://business.facebook.com/ads/manager/pixel/facebook_pixel/), because i really dont know which event to choose, and where to get code for that custom pixel.

As far as i got with my research, you have to insert *fbq('track', 'Lead')* somewhere in above pixel code, but i still have no idea, how to link that to submit button and how to get all this data to my facebook development panel.

Thank you for all your answers, Luka.

Comment: What have you tried so far? To track something on a button click you should just be able to use a JavaScript click handler to fire `fbq('track', 'CUSTOM_EVENT')`.

Comment: I have tried all, but everything slightly wrong..  Your comment helped me realise, that you must create new custom event in FB pixel admin panel, and then use JS click handler to fire the event..

So:


1. I created new custom pixel in admin panel named "blabla"
2. i used code 
        onclick="fbq('track', 'blabla')"

and now its working as it should. Thank you for your help

Comment: No problem! Facebook provide a set of predefined events such as ADD_TO_CART etc but you have the ability to create your own custom events for what ever purpose you need.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do that by adding an event within the button. As you already have your base code set up and working, you just need to add the standard event code:

```
<button onClick="fbq('track', 'Purchase');">Button Text</button>
```

If you prefer, you can create a function that triggers the event:

```
<script>
function onClick() {
  fbq('track', 'Purchase');
};
</script>
```

And then call it, to fire the event when clicking the button:

```
<button onClick="onClick()">Buy Now</button>
```

Comment: But how do you add the lately needed parameters `currency` and `value` here?